# Click on a button and get the other button click automatically using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, button

I have 2 buttons in a different div tag and I want that if I click on one button (suppose in div A) then automatically the other button (suppose in div B) should get clicked simultaneously using Angularjs or Javascript.
Is there any way to do so?

Comment: please share your code too

Comment: What it your exact requirement ? also share expected and current result of your try ?

Comment: @user2486 my problem is solved thank you

Comment: @UsmanRana if I would have added the code it would have been more confusing to explain so i didnt

Comment: @webcode Welcome to stackoverflow. Before asking low quality questions make yourself understood how SO works. Please read this document carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help. Please note that there is a "vote" button near each question / answer. Also note that there is an grey tick near the answer question. This tick alows you to accept "right" answers.

Comment: In AngularJS you usually trigger functions that are binded to buttons. There is no need to simulate a click event, just call the function B inside the function A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want jquery `.trigger("click");` function

```js
function clicked1(){
  console.log('button 1 clicked');
  $("#btn2").trigger("click");
}
function clicked2(){
  console.log('button 2 clicked');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" onclick="clicked1()">Button1</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="clicked2()">Button1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
scope.div1ClickEvent = function(){
    scope.div2ClickEvent();
    //whatever else...?
}
```

where your `ng-click='div1clickEvent()'`

Comment: no the other button click functionality is to transit the page to the other and that is disabled for time being so i just wanted to click it in background (automatically) so that even if the button is disabled i can go to the other page @mike